# How do I get the Hadoop command ./start-all.sh to execute in terminal

Tags: hadoop

I am attempting to get Hadoop working and believe something small needs correcting. Problem is, I am not sure what to do here: After executing the following:

`./start-all.sh`

My terminal is showing:

`-bash: ./start-all.sh: No such file or directory`

I have attempted to modify my hdfs.site.xml, but this is also not working. Current looks like this:

```
  <property>
    <name>dfs.replication</name>
    <value>1</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

For reference, installation came from https://towardsdatascience.com/installing-hadoop-on-a-mac-ec01c67b003c

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Why did you delete the answer if it worked?

Answer (score 0):

Apologies for wasting anyones time with looking at my question. I was attempting to execute from the `bin` directory but after moving to the `sbin` directory, the `./start-all.sh` seems to be working now